# Add same custom view multiple times

Tags: objective-c

How to add same custom view as multiple times when clicking on add button. I tried to add using for loop but every times views are adding and overlapping previous views.

Comment: 1) Create new variable each time. 2) Desgin view through coding or create a different class with xib.(Dont use view with IBOutlet Connection)

Comment: you need to remove previous view before add new custom view, or if you using story board designed view then also you need to remove and add sub view again with button press

Comment: removing is working but in views i hve text field so i remove the data is lost and new view is creating..

Comment: Create new variable each time is not working.                                                         2)Yes using different xib. still no use

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
-(IBAction)addNewCustomView {

  YourView *view = [[YouView alloc] init];
  // view.property = set
  [self.view addSubview:view];

}
```

Comment: `  for(int i=1;i<=inputNumber;i++){
        
       
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(5,i*120,backgroundView.frame.size.width-10,110);
        NSArray* nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView"
                                                          owner:self
                                                        options:nil];
        
        customView = [ nibViews objectAtIndex: 0];
        
        [customView  setFrame:frame];
        customView.delegate = self;
        [backgroundView addSubview:customView];
}`